# Penrose diagrams and Holographic Principle

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, event-horizon, holographic-principle

What would the Penrose Diagram look like that represented a black hole (call it Black Hole-B), inside of a massive black hole (Black Hole-A), in our universe?

and, as inside of the Penrose diagram for BH-A (PD-1), would be attached to the upper diagonal edge of our universe's Penrose Diagram (PD-0),
a) Would the Penrose diagram for BH-B (PD-2), lie along the upper diagonal edge of PD-1, (the Penrose Diagram for BH-A)?

and, since radial "Space-Like" *direction lines?* in PD-0 become "Time-like" in PD-1, and vice versa, would they then switch back in PD-2 and revert back to the way they were in our own universe?

Comment: Actually, I was only asking how the penrose diagram would look... My assumptions are only that you can have a black hole inside our visible universe, and, if it is true (as posited by the descriptions I have read, that from the perspective of someone who has fallen into a black hole, that he/she is in ordinary 4-D space time, similar to our own, that a black hole can form in that space time, then how would the Penrose diagram (and the geodesics within it),  for that tripley-nested scenario look?

Comment: First, thanks for your time!.  But I know that for two black holes in *our* space time, that one cannot *fall* into the other. But if the laws of Physics in the interior of a black hole are in fact (from the perspective of an observer in the interior), identical to the laws of Physics in *our* space-time), then if sufficient matter within the black hole's interior collapsed to within its Schwartzchild radius, it would indeed form a black hole inside of that black hole, no?

Comment: I think this is a good question. I've even seen a paper saying that inside a very large and rotating BH, stable orbits can exist. Is it possible for a star to inhabit such an orbit, and then undergo collapse into a 2nd BH?

Comment: @safesphere, I edited to clarify..  I am asking this to clarify what I see as possible inconsistency. Some ideas I have seen presented by fairly well-respected individuals imply that an observer who falls through event horizon of a *very very* large Black Hole would not percieve anything unusual.... but the way they describe the switching of space-like and time-like *direction lines* belies that.

Comment: @Charles the statement is true about an observer perceiving nothing unusual in his local vicinity, provided that vicinity is small enough that the local gravity field is uniform. The $r$ coordinate becoming timelike is a coordinate-dependent effect.  As a general principle, in an observer's local vicinity the spacetime is always Minkowskian (or can be written as such)

Comment: That works in a similar way to Taylor's theorem in calculus, that for well behaved (continuous, differentiable, etc) functions, a local approximation can always be made which is linear.

Comment: @safesphere, Thanks, I made that change, (hopefully if I understood you, properly). And yes, I understand Taylor/McLaurin series (the derivation for Euler's equation!). if the analogy is only valid locally, where the gravity field is uniform, then the that invalidates any of the popular notions that we are already inside of a massive black hole... no?

Comment: I have always been intrigued by the apparent similarities between the holographic description of our space-time, and the fact that as an observer accelerates to velocities near c, that the universe around him/her begins to appear more and more like a two dimensional surface normal to his direction of motion..., and moving in time at higher and higher velocities relative to a clock in his/her frame of reference.